# How to remove/replace first occurrence of character from the right using JavaScript dynamic approach?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

example

```
var string = "ACABBCAA";
var a = "A";
var b = "B";
var c= "C";
```

output:

```
removeLastChar(string,a);  //output ACABBCA
removeLastChar(string,b);  //output ACABCAA
removeLastChar(string,c);  //output ACABBAA
```

What I have tried so far?

Solution 1

```
 function removeLastChar(string,char){
        result = string.replace(new RegExp('/'+char+'$/'), "");
        return result;
    }
```

Solution 2

```
function removeLastChar(string,char){
    result = string.replace('/'+char+'$/', "");
    return result;
}
```

I already asked [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630230/replace-last-character-of-string-using-javascript) but not working out.

Comment: IMO RegExps are overkill for such problem

Comment: @Rajesh I have already stored capital letter in a variable. it is not letter, it is variable.. please read full

Comment: You should consider using [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: @hindmost how can i replace or remove the last occurrence of a character using lastindexof? it will just help me out to search it in string, I already know the character

Comment: Begin from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting)

Comment: reverse the string, remove the character and reverse it back.

Comment: @Rohit Kashyap Too complicated way for such simple problem

Comment: I know but since you came up with a better approach already, I was suggesting an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lastIndexOf` and `splice` with spread notation `...`.

```
function removeLastChar(string, char) {
  let strArr = [...string];
  strArr.splice(string.lastIndexOf(char), 1);
  return strArr.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my way to do it

```
var text = "ACABBCAA";
var a = "A";
var b = "B";
var c= "C";
function removeLastChar(string,char){
  let charLastPosition = string.lastIndexOf(char);
  let newString = string.substring(0, charLastPosition) + string.substring(charLastPosition + 1);
  return newString;
}

document.write(removeLastChar(text, a));
```

if you wanna replace you can do it un this way.

```
var text = "Notion,Data,Identity,";
var a = "A";
var b = "B";
var c= "C";
function replaceLastChar(string,char, charToReplace){
    let charLastPosition = string.lastIndexOf(char);
    let newString = string.substring(0, charLastPosition) + charToReplace + string.substring(charLastPosition + 1);
  return newString;
}

document.write(replaceLastChar(text, ',', '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic regex like this: `${char}(?=[^${char}]*$)` (For `B` it would be: `B(?=[^B]+$)`). This will match the last instace of a character and `replace` it with empty string

```js
function removeLastChar(str, char) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${char}(?=[^${char}]*$)`)
  return str.replace(regex, '')
}

console.log(removeLastChar("ACABBCAA", "A"));
console.log(removeLastChar("ACABBCAA", "B"));
console.log(removeLastChar("ACABBCAA", "C"));
```

Comment: Instead of a negated character class, why not a simple negated lookahead?

Comment: @JackBashford how would that look like, for example `A`?